# Adding Service Worker to LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

How do we add a service worker to an [LWC local](https://lwc.dev/) application?

I am trying to add a service worker to an LWC application. I have added the sw.js to the project but it shows an error while registering the service worker that the file was not found. I also tried to see if the file can be added using a script tag but got the same issue there as well.

Comment: Hi @manish have you got the solution on this?